# Why does this error keep popping up? Index out of range: Unity 2D/WebGL C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, indexoutofrangeexception

I am relatively new to Unity and have a recurring error. I am creating a simple 2D game in which the player can shoot these bullets at enemies, which are prefabs. In Unity itself, everything works fine but when I try to make a build in WebGL to play in my browser, and error keeps popping up saying my memory is out of bounds or index is out of range.

I have tried doing this on chrome, firefox, and explorer but the same thing keeps happening. I have tried searching the internet but have found no answers on how to fix this problem so far. Here is the code for my bullet script, if it helps.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WebShooter : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot() {
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo) {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0y1k.jpg

Comment: Sounds like you're having an issue with not having enough memory allocated to the game. May have to look at solutions to increase the allocated memory or decrease the amount of used memory. For the latter, may want to consider something like [Object Pooling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA) your bullets and enemies. As for the Index out of range, that may be coming from some script trying to reference an object after it was destroyed so maybe double check your logic that deals with objects which can be destroyed.

Comment: I believe that either the enemy type or the bullet itself may be referenced after it is destroyed, so I will try to fix this problem. If that fails, I will try Object Pooling. I will update you if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with the fact that you are not destroying the bullets that don't hit the gameobject? do you have any code to destroy them once they go off the screen?

```
If(Mathf.Abs(bulletPrefab.position) - Mathf.Abs(firePoint.position) > 10)
{
   Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

I'm just thinking that you might be overloading the memory with lots of undestroyed bullets flying off into infinity

Comment: Yes, the bullets do get destroyed in the enemy script. When the enemy gets hit by a bullet, the state of the enemy itself is set to false and the thing that it collides with gets deleted. It might be the enemies that are causing this problem.

Comment: What happens to the bullets that miss? are they flying off the screen?

Comment: I have a despawning script that lets those bullets get deleted as well once they move out of the range of the camera. Also, here is the snippet of code that destroys the bullets and sets the enemies to false.

Destroy(other.gameObject);
this.gameObject.SetActive(false);

Do you think there is a way to delete the enemies as well without deleting the prefab itself?

Comment: Oh hold on nevermind to fix this problem I added the same code that destroys whatever the bullet hits so it is fixed, but even with this the error is still there.

Comment: Oh damn, thought it might just be a bug like that or something.  if its working ok in unity and your bullets aren't the problem it must be something else! sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with WebGL or something, but thanks for the help nonetheless :)